# Grouping 2 dataframes by month, year then visualizing percent of Green month by month

Tags: pandas, group-by, data-visualization, filtering, transformation

I am working in Python and am trying to group 2 different dataframes by month and year, then visualizing the percent within a specific category over a timeline but on the same visual. Sort of like a trend analysis of 2 different porfolios. Each dataframe has a Project Name, Project Health, Date. Within the Project Health, there are 3 identifiers: Green, Red and Yellow. What I am essentially hoping to do is to visualize the Percent Green for each dataframe, over the Date column, onto the same visual. I have gotten far but am stuck at the step below.
See below for code:

```
Cur.groupby("Customer Signed Date")["ProjectHealth"].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

From that point, I am stuck at the visualizing aspect.

Comment: Are you looking for a line plot that shows how green varies over a time period? Could you add some sample data that you are using to the question?

Comment: Hello @viggnah Thank you so much for providing yourself as help! I am eternally grateful. I am indeed looking for a plot that shows how green varies over time but for two separate dataframes and then visualizing both of them on the same visual.  '''df'''

Comment: Could you addd some sample data from the two dataframes?

Comment: Absolutely @viggnah.